# PHP - Wanting to select specific number of rows and order them from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a formula which is designed to create a scoring method. Users input a value that "gold", "silver" and "bronze" should each be worth. These medals are then found in the database, and the total number of each medal is multiplied by the amount specified by the user. A "priority value" is also selected by the user which is to do with a separate field in the table.

The total value of the medals is stored in the medaltotal variable. The priority value is divided by this variable to give the total score.

All of this so far works as expected.

I now need the table to be sorted in order of highest "score" to the lowest "score" as defined by the methods above. Once this is complete, it should echo back only the first 10 results as so to give a "top 10" based upon score.

The relative code that I've used so far is as follows:

```
while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
    $priorityvalue = ($row('gdp') / 100000000);
    $goldvalue = $row[strtolower('gold')] * $gold;
    $silvervalue = $row[strtolower('silver')] * $silver;
    $bronzevalue = $row[strtolower('bronze')] * $bronze;
    $score = ($priorityvalue / $medaltotal);
}
```

I've considering tinkering with mysql_fetch_array, but unsure as to which method would be best to use from here. Any advice?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  I, for one, don't understand what you are doing.  For instance, a user would only have one row so what are you ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

1. Read each row & assigned score into an array or object.
2. Add each of these to a "result list" or array.
3. Sort the result list, on score.
4. Print the first 10.

Since the order you read from the database **is not** the order you wish to print in, it's necessary to store the data in a temporary data-structure & sort it.

As above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this SQL returns the results you want:

```
select t.*, priority / medaltotal as score
from table t
order by score desc
limit 10
```